# How to send mails with queue without executing php artisan queue:listen?

Tags: php, laravel, email, terminal, queue

I have a function in orderController which sends email about new order to all sellers:

```
public function sendMailToSellers($order, $orderDetails)
    {

        $sellers = Role::with('users')->where('name', 'seller')->get()->first()->users->toArray();
        $emails = [];
        foreach ($sellers as $seller) {
            $emails[] = $seller['email'];
        }


        Mail::queue(green.'.orderEmail', ['order_details' => $orderDetails, 'order' => $order], function ($message) use ($emails, $order) {
            $message->from('myMail@gmail.com', 'MyShop');
            $message->bcc($emails);
            $message->subject('New order №' . $order['order_id'].' '. $order['created_at']);
        });

    }
```

but the problem is that email sends only when I run in terminal php artisan queue:listen. I tried to run nohup php artisan queue:listen, but terminal tells me that nohup doesn't exists :c.

Comment: Do you know `supervisor`? Have a look:
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: Its for linux, i have WIndows

Comment: So try use `cron`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling